# How to deploy apps on herkou which use dlib?

Tags: django, heroku, boost, cmake, dlib

I have been trying to deploy a Django web app to Heroku and I have dlib as a dependency. I have tried adding the build pack for which installs dlib and opencv. [This](https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku16-buildpack-python3-opencv-dlib) is the buildpack that I have tried. But this does not work as this has become [stale](https://github.com/J-A-M-E-5/heroku16-buildpack-python3-opencv-dlib/issues/1). I don't know if there is any other way to install dlib on Heroku?

Here is the requirements.txt file for my app:

```
dj-database-url==0.3.0
dj-static==0.0.6
gunicorn==19.7.1
Unipath==1.0
python-decouple==3
click==6.7
numpy==1.15.4
Pillow==5.2.0
face-recognition-models==0.3.0
cmake
Werkzeug==0.14.1
face-recognition==1.2.3
boost==0.1
boost-py
dlib==19.4.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
whitenoise==3.2
jsonschema==2.6.0
```

and this is the error that I get when I push to heroku master:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 704 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting Django==2.1.1 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/7e/fc068d164b32552ae3a8f8d5d0280c083f2e8d553e71ecacc21927564561/Django-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.3MB)
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ef/b6/9283fcf61ced22bf90e7b4a84ba5b53d126b2c9b0dc9b667347698097026/dj_database_url-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting dj-static==0.0.6 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2b/8f/77a4b8ec50c821193bf9682c7896f12fd0418eb3711a7d66796ede59c23b/dj-static-0.0.6.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.7.1 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/64/32/becbd4089a4c06f0f9f538a76e9fe0b19a08f010bcb47dcdbfbc640cdf7d/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111kB)
remote:        Collecting Unipath==1.0 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/8e/7efe289440c9d3b3f2784516fef1362428d1c00d35ca31c39d7bee1412e8/Unipath-1.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting python-decouple==3 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/fc/9f3ec3f7844f9045406562512dbb599e9576e0c2ce3192a5e4d459f66e99/python-decouple-3.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting click==6.7 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/34/c1/8806f99713ddb993c5366c362b2f908f18269f8d792aff1abfd700775a77/click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
remote:        Collecting numpy==1.15.4 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ff/7f/9d804d2348471c67a7d8b5f84f9bc59fd1cefa148986f2b74552f8573555/numpy-1.15.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (13.9MB)
remote:        Collecting Pillow==5.2.0 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/24/f53ff6b61b3d728b90934bddb4f03f8ab584a7f49299bf3bde56e2952612/Pillow-5.2.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0MB)
remote:        Collecting face-recognition-models==0.3.0 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cf/3b/4fd8c534f6c0d1b80ce0973d01331525538045084c73c153ee6df20224cf/face_recognition_models-0.3.0.tar.gz (100.1MB)
remote:        Collecting cmake (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/c4/e69313ade2a3e992e7178744b0e56bdd8f23e79e15066a68cf490504beed/cmake-3.13.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (15.9MB)
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==0.14.1 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/20/c4/12e3e56473e52375aa29c4764e70d1b8f3efa6682bef8d0aae04fe335243/Werkzeug-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (322kB)
remote:        Collecting face-recognition==1.2.3 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 13))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/ed/ad9a28042f373d4633fc8b49109b623597d6f193d3bbbef7780a5ee8eef2/face_recognition-1.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting boost==0.1 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 14))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/e9/fd77f318eba4976c9ed9df341c13daebe69cace8723dbd0f3d39a0dddb08/boost-0.1.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting boost-py (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 15))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/be/28a09dacd0770d281bd3798f148dc431503b726b7219cec1fdb6faca46e6/boost_py-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting dlib==19.4.0 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1d/76/0f91fde37a83a40cf27e6cabd900b975c2667c522a07ae38e31cda2fa486/dlib-19.4.0.tar.gz (4.0MB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.7.5 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 17))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5e/d0/9e2b3ed43001ebed45caf56d5bb9d44ed3ebd68e12b87845bfa7bcd46250/psycopg2-2.7.5-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==3.2 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 18))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/7b/2d8276a56b6ebb7c0b8652a31e535df67f0e4152037b33ce036e79146ac3/whitenoise-3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting jsonschema==2.6.0 (from -r /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/requirements.txt (line 19))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/77/de/47e35a97b2b05c2fadbec67d44cfcdcd09b8086951b331d82de90d2912da/jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Installing collected packages: Django, dj-database-url, dj-static, gunicorn, Unipath, python-decouple, click, numpy, Pillow, face-recognition-models, cmake, Werkzeug, dlib, face-recognition, boost, boost-py, psycopg2, whitenoise, jsonschema
remote:          Running setup.py install for dj-static: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for dj-static: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for Unipath: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for Unipath: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for python-decouple: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for python-decouple: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for face-recognition-models: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for face-recognition-models: finished with status 'done'
remote:          Running setup.py install for dlib: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for dlib: finished with status 'error'
remote:            Complete output from command /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-otsn5okf/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-diaey5c7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
remote:            running install
remote:            running build
remote:            Detected Python architecture: 64bit
remote:            Detected platform: linux
remote:            Configuring cmake ...
remote:            -- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
remote:            -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
remote:            -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
remote:            -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
remote:            -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
remote:            -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
remote:            -- Detecting C compile features
remote:            -- Detecting C compile features - done
remote:            -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
remote:            -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
remote:            -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
remote:            -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
remote:            -- Detecting CXX compile features
remote:            -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
remote:            CMake Warning at /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1775 (message):
remote:              No header defined for python-py34; skipping header check
remote:            Call Stack (most recent call first):
remote:              /tmp/pip-build-otsn5okf/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:61 (FIND_PACKAGE)
remote:              CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
remote:            -- Could NOT find Boost
remote:            CMake Warning at /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cmake/data/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1775 (message):
remote:              No header defined for python-py35; skipping header check
remote:            Call Stack (most recent call first):
remote:              /tmp/pip-build-otsn5okf/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:63 (FIND_PACKAGE)
remote:              CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
remote:            -- Could NOT find Boost
remote:            -- Could NOT find Boost
remote:            -- Could NOT find Boost
remote:            -- Found PythonLibs: /tmp/build_6d2057dd8ed43f6db2772ce68b91cc1d/.heroku/python/lib/libpython3.6m.a (found suitable version "3.6.8", minimum required is "3.4")
remote:            --  *****************************************************************************************************
remote:            --  To compile Boost.Python yourself download boost from boost.org and then go into the boost root folder
remote:            --  and run these commands:
remote:            --     ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python
remote:            --     ./b2
remote:            --     sudo ./b2 install
remote:            --  *****************************************************************************************************
remote:            CMake Error at /tmp/pip-build-otsn5okf/dlib/dlib/cmake_utils/add_python_module:116 (message):
remote:               Boost python library not found.
remote:            Call Stack (most recent call first):
remote:              CMakeLists.txt:6 (include)
remote:            -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
remote:            See also "/tmp/pip-build-otsn5okf/dlib/tools/python/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
remote:            error: cmake configuration failed!
remote:            
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "/app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-otsn5okf/dlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-diaey5c7-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-otsn5okf/dlib/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to app.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/app.git'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
boost==0.1
cmake==0.7.1
boost-py
face_recognition_models
face_recognition
dlib>=19.3.0
numpy
Pillow
scipy>=0.17.0
aniso8601==1.2.0
asn1crypto==0.24.0
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
cryptography==1.9
Flask==0.12.1
Flask-Ask==0.9.7
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
pycparser==2.18
pyOpenSSL==17.0.0
python-dateutil==2.7.2
PyYAML==3.12
requests==2.18.4
six==1.11.0
Unidecode==1.0.22
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

You need cmake to install dlib. To install cmake in heroku you need to buildpack cmake and set that build in order to install dlib.

You can use this buildpack for cmake heroku-buildpack-cmake

**Do this in your CLI**

1. Login to heroku
2. copy paste `heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/VovchikMonkey/heroku-buildpack-cmake.git`
3. And finally set the buildpack  `heroku buildpacks:set
       https://github.com/Starkast/heroku-buildpack-cmake`
4. And then deploy 
   `$ git add .

   $ git commit -am "make it better"

   $ git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

You need set buildpack as `heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git`